# Nuget, TFS online build failing. It is getting the packages

Tags: c#, tfs, msbuild, nuget

I am using TFS online and trying to get a CI build working. The project builds locally, nuget is set to get the packages and according to the diag from the build server it is getting those as well.

From the Build Diagnostics

> EnableNuGetPackageRestore = True

Under get workspace I have

> Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Tools;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Content\Scripts;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Content\Scripts\modernizr-2.6.2.js;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Tools\common.ps1;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Tools\install.ps1;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\Modernizr.2.6.2\Tools\uninstall.ps1;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\MyCouch.0.12.0.nupkg;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\net40;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\net45;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\netcore45;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\net40\MyCouch.Net40.XML;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\net45\MyCouch.Net45.XML;C10
>   Getting C:\a\Sources\Src\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\netcore45\MyCouch.NetCore45.xml;C10

A little further down i have where it is looking for the primary reference:

> Primary reference "MyCouch.Net45". (TaskId:50)
>   ...
>   For SearchPath "{HintPathFromItem}". (TaskId:50)
>    Considered "..\packages\MyCouch.0.12.0\lib\net45\MyCouch.Net45.dll", but it didn't exist. (TaskId:50)

but then it fails when build the DAL repo

> CouchDB.cs (7): The type or namespace name 'MyCouch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   IRepoCouchDb.cs (2): The type or namespace name 'MyCouch' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   CouchDB.cs (77): The type or namespace name 'ViewQuery' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   IRepoCouchDb.cs (12): The type or namespace name 'ViewQuery' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

nuget.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    <add key="EnableNuGetPackageRestore" value="true" />
</solution>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Do you have a NuGet.config file checked in. If so, what is the contents?

Comment: Yes i did, i could get this to work on a local build server, but with TFS online it would not work. I just stuck with using a local build server for this project.